# Bash : what does we call the syntax and what purpose it is used

Tags: linux, bash

```
prefix="N774"
prefix_trunc=${prefix:1:3}
```

what does ${prefix:1:3} do.
I have searched for it but i did not get any answere.

Thank you

Comment: P.E. parameter expansion see https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html

Comment: If you have bash installed.  `PAGER='less +/^[[:space:]]*parameter\ expansion' man bash`

Comment: `echo "${prefix_trunc}"` should show you what it does, change the numbers and see what change and read the  manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### What does `${prefix:1:3}` do?

It is called Shell Parameter Expansion.

> **Shell Parameter Expansion**
>
> The $ character introduces parameter expansion, command substitution,
>   or arithmetic expansion. The parameter name or symbol to be expanded
>   can be enclosed in braces, which are optional but serve to protect the
>   variable to be expanded from characters immediately following it which
>   could be interpreted as part of the name.
>
> When braces are used, the matching ending brace is the first } not
>   escaped by a backslash or within a quoted string, and not within an
>   embedded arithmetic expansion, command substitution, or parameter
>   expansion.
>
> The basic form of parameter expansion is:
>
> ```
> ${parameter}
> ```
>
> The value of parameter is substituted. The braces are required when
>   parameter is a positional parameter with more than one digit, or when
>   parameter is followed by a character that is not to be interpreted as
>   part of its name.
>
> ...
>
> ```
> ${parameter:offset}
> ${parameter:offset:length}
> ```
>
> Expands to up to length characters of parameter starting at the
>   character specified by offset. If length is omitted, expands to the
>   substring of parameter starting at the character specified by offset.
>   length and offset are arithmetic expressions. This is referred to as
>   Substring Expansion.
>
> - length must evaluate to a number greater than or equal to zero.
> - If offset evaluates to a number less than zero, the value is used as an offset from the end of the value of parameter.
> - If parameter is @, the result is length positional parameters beginning at offset.
> - If parameter is an array name indexed by @ or *, the result is the length members of the array beginning with ${parameter[offset]}.
> - Substring indexing is zero-based unless the positional parameters are used, in which case the indexing starts at 1.

Source [How-To: shell expansion - Linux - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/bash/syntax-expand.html)